How to send emails with unique attachments in Google Apps Script?
I have implemented a function in Apps script, with the following goals:

Reference tab: Tracks a list of Users and their coinciding emails. Also provides unique links (in column N), which are separate spreadsheets, that store a user's records.

Report - Current Processing Period tab: Provides Admin staff a button to 'Email All'

Primary goal: Implement a master function, that sends unique emails to All users simultaneously, each with an attachment, that stores their coinciding records.


Current issue: The emails are being sent successfully as anticipated, but they're currently in separate functions (7). How can this be accomplished in one main function?
I have searched for comparable questions, but I'm having trouble identifying an example of attaching a unique sheet for each user on the email distribution list.
function sendEmailReportInsp1() {
    let token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1FihtFsJ6IxEEO38rTmmYtQySp6nE1ofuT8s4TNrqO0I");
    var range = range ? range : "A1:K109";//Set the default to whatever you want
  var [[emailInspName],, [emailAddr]] = spreadsheet.getRange("B4:B6").getDisplayValues();
  var [[file_name]] = spreadsheet.getRange("A8").getDisplayValues();

    let spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.getId();
    let sheetId = "1427007470";
  
    let sheetUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + spreadsheetId + "/export?" + "format=xlsx" + "&gid=" + sheetId + 
    '&range=' + range + 
    "&portrait=true" + "&exportFormat=pdf";
    let request = UrlFetchApp.fetch(sheetUrl, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        }
    });
    let content = request.getContent();
    let message = {
        to: emailAddr,
        subject: "Independent Contractor Invoice and Inspection Statement: " + emailInspName,
        body: "Attached is your statement of Inspections for the latest pay period.\n\nAny questions?\n\nPlease contact Home Commercial Inspections.\n\nThank you,\nMr. James Jones",
        attachments: [{
            fileName: "Inspections: " + file_name,
            content: content,
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
        }]
    }
    MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}


function sendEmailReportInsp2() {
    let token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1GBL_aex6FHQ1fFegB2Oue5GMp0RGpcCefhaMvwNDNsQ');
    var range = range ? range : "A1:K109";//Set the default to whatever you want
  var [[emailInspName],, [emailAddr]] = spreadsheet.getRange("B4:B6").getDisplayValues();
  var [[file_name]] = spreadsheet.getRange("A8").getDisplayValues();

    let spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.getId();
    let sheetId = "870087782";
  
    let sheetUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + spreadsheetId + "/export?" + "format=xlsx" + "&gid=" + sheetId + 
    '&range=' + range + 
    "&portrait=true" + "&exportFormat=pdf";
    let request = UrlFetchApp.fetch(sheetUrl, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        }
    });
    let content = request.getContent();
    let message = {
        to: emailAddr,
        subject: "Independent Contractor Invoice and Inspection Statement: ",
        body: emailInspName + "\n\nPlease find attached your invoice and inspection statement for the processing period.\n\nFeel free to reach out if you have any questions.\n\nThanks,\nHome Commercial Inspections",
        attachments: [{
            fileName: "Invoice and Inspection statement for processing period",
            content: content,
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
        }]
    }
    MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}

function sendEmailReportInsp3() {
    let token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1wWtv5PiTZVNKd9pi94brQOdy44yqToSoeO3a-wyyWVg");
    var range = range ? range : "A1:K109";//Set the default to whatever you want
  var [[emailInspName],, [emailAddr]] = spreadsheet.getRange("B4:B6").getDisplayValues();
  var [[file_name]] = spreadsheet.getRange("A8").getDisplayValues();

    let spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.getId();
    let sheetId = "394261269";
  
    let sheetUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + spreadsheetId + "/export?" + "format=xlsx" + "&gid=" + sheetId + 
    '&range=' + range + 
    "&portrait=true" + "&exportFormat=pdf";
    let request = UrlFetchApp.fetch(sheetUrl, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        }
    });
    let content = request.getContent();
    let message = {
        to: emailAddr,
        subject: "Independent Contractor Invoice and Inspection Statement: " + emailInspName,
        body: "Attached is your statement of Inspections for the latest pay period.\n\nAny questions?\n\nPlease contact Home Commercial Inspections.\n\nThank you,\nMr. James Jones",
        attachments: [{
            fileName: "Invoice and Inspection statement for processing period",
            content: content,
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
        }]
    }
    MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}


function sendEmailReportInsp4() {
    let token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1OAFDcl81ryrRxQNWv2mxs5ufBeN-DKNobU3PbB1dYSM");
    var range = range ? range : "A1:K109";//Set the default to whatever you want
  var [[emailInspName],, [emailAddr]] = spreadsheet.getRange("B4:B6").getDisplayValues();
  var [[file_name]] = spreadsheet.getRange("A8").getDisplayValues();

    let spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.getId();
    let sheetId = "415034801";
  
    let sheetUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + spreadsheetId + "/export?" + "format=xlsx" + "&gid=" + sheetId + 
    '&range=' + range + 
    "&portrait=true" + "&exportFormat=pdf";
    let request = UrlFetchApp.fetch(sheetUrl, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        }
    });
    let content = request.getContent();
    let message = {
        to: emailAddr,
        subject: "Independent Contractor Invoice and Inspection Statement: " + emailInspName,
        body: "Attached is your statement of Inspections for the latest pay period.\n\nAny questions?\n\nPlease contact Home Commercial Inspections.\n\nThank you,\nMr. James Jones",
        attachments: [{
            fileName: "Inspections: " + file_name,
            content: content,
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
        }]
    }
    MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}


function sendEmailReportInsp5() {
    let token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1RYXgtJZLPcTKzbmTbfu46T-DVLv5s2jHTJibxSJZ3ZE");
    var range = range ? range : "A1:K109";//Set the default to whatever you want
  var [[emailInspName],, [emailAddr]] = spreadsheet.getRange("B4:B6").getDisplayValues();
  var [[file_name]] = spreadsheet.getRange("A8").getDisplayValues();

    let spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.getId();
    let sheetId = "1276626525";
  
    let sheetUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + spreadsheetId + "/export?" + "format=xlsx" + "&gid=" + sheetId + 
    '&range=' + range + 
    "&portrait=true" + "&exportFormat=pdf";
    let request = UrlFetchApp.fetch(sheetUrl, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        }
    });
    let content = request.getContent();
    let message = {
        to: emailAddr,
        subject: "Independent Contractor Invoice and Inspection Statement: " + emailInspName,
        body: "Attached is your statement of Inspections for the latest pay period.\n\nAny questions?\n\nPlease contact Home Commercial Inspections.\n\nThank you,\nMr. James Jones",
        attachments: [{
            fileName: "Inspections: " + file_name,
            content: content,
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
        }]
    }
    MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}


function sendEmailReportInsp6() {
    let token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("19IjM4PD7PgoGSOLiGNKqyuJUdDMUICGlEvRAUuR_AFs");
    var range = range ? range : "A1:K109";//Set the default to whatever you want
  var [[emailInspName],, [emailAddr]] = spreadsheet.getRange("B4:B6").getDisplayValues();

    let spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.getId();
    let sheetId = "1453684542";

  var [[file_name]] = spreadsheet.getRange("A8").getDisplayValues();
  
    let sheetUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + spreadsheetId + "/export?" + "format=xlsx" + "&gid=" + sheetId + 
    '&range=' + range + 
    "&portrait=true" + "&exportFormat=pdf";
    let request = UrlFetchApp.fetch(sheetUrl, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        }
    });
    let content = request.getContent();
    let message = {
        to: emailAddr,
        subject: "Independent Contractor Invoice and Inspection Statement: " + emailInspName,
        body: "Attached is your statement of Inspections for the latest pay period.\n\nAny questions?\n\nPlease contact Home Commercial Inspections.\n\nThank you,\nMr. James Jones",
        attachments: [{
            fileName: "Inspections: " + file_name,
            content: content,
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
        }]
    }
    MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}


// *** Unique Email Template (requires sheets gid=2115259318 and gid=1361306336)
function sendEmailReport_SpecialRep() {
    let token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
    let spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1ztpubW5-h9myOpC9GGMfxzGoQYtM46czOqiE8tidCl8');
    var range = range ? range : "A1:K109";//Set the default to whatever you want
  var [[emailInspName],, [emailAddr]] = spreadsheet.getRange("L2:L4").getDisplayValues();
  var [[file_name]] = spreadsheet.getRange("A1").getDisplayValues();

    let spreadsheetId = spreadsheet.getId();
    let sheetId = "2115259318"; //gid=2115259318 and gid=1361306336
  
    let sheetUrl = "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + spreadsheetId + "/export?" + "format=xlsx" + "&gid=" + sheetId + 
    '&range=' + range + 
    "&portrait=true" + "&exportFormat=pdf";
    let request = UrlFetchApp.fetch(sheetUrl, {
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
        }
    });
    let content = request.getContent();
    let message = {
        to: emailAddr,
        subject: "Independent Contractor (IC) Current Payee Totals",
        body: emailInspName + "\n\nPlease find attached the IC Payee Totals for the current processing period.\n\nFeel free to reach out if you have any questions.\n\nThanks,\nHome Commercial Inspections",
        attachments: [{
            fileName: "Payee Totals for current processing period",
            content: content,
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
        }]
    }
    MailApp.sendEmail(message);
}

For example:
Name:               (Same Email Subj,Body)  tab (to be Attached in email): 
James Smith         TestEmail01@gmail.com   gid=1427007470 
Matthew Steele      TestEmail02@gmail.com   gid=870087782
Megan Stallworth    TestEmail03@gmail.com   gid=394261269
Blair Tutye         TestEmail04@gmail.com   gid=415034801
Keith Rogers        TestEmail05@gmail.com   gid=1276626525
Miguel Quarles      TestEmail06@gmail.com   gid=1453684542
    
Name:               (unique Email Subj,Body) tab 1 and tab 2    
Bobby Sanchez       TestEmail09@gmail.com   gid=2115259318 and gid=1361306336

Dummy spreadsheet


Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed a simple script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

@Tanaike, thanks for following up and sorry about my original message being unclear. In reviewing your sample script, yes in essence this is sufficient. Initially what I was envisioning was assembling a For loop, which runs through the Email distribution list

Thank you for replying. About Initially what I was envisioning was assembling a For loop, which runs through the Email distribution list, when I saw your showing script, I noticed that the ranges of emailInspName, emailAddr, file_name are not the same of all functions, and also, subject, body, the filename of attachments are not the same of all functions. So, I proposed the script in my answer. If my answer was not useful, I apologize for this situation.

About your question The emails are being sent successfully as anticipated, but they're currently in separate functions (7). How can this be accomplished in one main function?, as a simple script, how about the following script?
In this modification, from The emails are being sent successfully as anticipated, it supposes that each function works fine.
Sample script:
By this modification, when sample is run, all 7 functions are run in order.
function sample() {
  sendEmailReportInsp1();
  sendEmailReportInsp2();
  sendEmailReportInsp3();
  sendEmailReportInsp4();
  sendEmailReportInsp5();
  sendEmailReportInsp6();
  sendEmailReport_SpecialRep();
}

